# Add Calendar event to OUTLOOK and iCal

Tags: asp.net, outlook, google-calendar-api, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I am trying to insert the calendar event into the Outlook as well as iCal(iphone calendar). Is it possible to add the events into these calendar through the website. As i am creating an event in Google calendar and wants to insert the same into outlook and ical if user clicks on corresponding button.
Currently i am doing it with downloading ICS and VCS file, but i want to insert directly into the calendar don't want to download the calendar.

Comment: Is you want to add your web calendar in to outlook then there are multiple ways available.  like sending iCal files via mail or passing your web URL into outlook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible for you to share some links with me.. actually i find the way to insert the event into Outlook but unable to find the way to insert in ICal.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are able generate ICS files at your end.

Actually I am php guy I have less experience in ASP. But I am sure there is nothing in ICS that you can't do with ASP. You just need to save your events in database and update your ICS file with all events from database.

You just need a url which generates ICS file on execution with the all event details inside it. As like you configure your email in outlook the same you can configure your url. Outlook will automatically create a calendar and will save event details inside the calendar.